# Can't get basic jQuery logic to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have this button in my HTML that basically collapses/expands the `#leftmenu` and it's working okay: `<a id="menutoggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#leftmenu">Placeholder</a>`

I want to accomplish this:

1. If `#leftmenu` is visible when you load the page then add
   `top:-10px` property to `#contentfix`.
2. If `#leftmenu` is collapsed by clicking the collapse button then remove `top:-10px` property from `#contentfix`.
3. If `#leftmenu` is expanded by clicking the collapse button then add `top:-10px` property to `#contentfix`.

I basically want the `top:-10px` property in my `#contentfix` whenever `#leftmenu` is visible and `top:0px` whenever it is hidden. Regardless of whether page had it visible/hidden by default or you changed it by clicking the collapse button.

Here's my current attempt:

```
if ($("#leftmenu").is(":visible")) {
    $('#contentfix').css('top','-10px');
    var visible = 1;
}

$('#menutoggle').click(function(e) {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
    if (visible == 0){
        $('#contentfix').css('top','-10px');
        visible = 1;
    } else {
        $('#contentfix').css('top','0px');
        visible = 0;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to use `$(document).ready()`. Moreover you can cache jQuery objects and do not need to set a visible variable and write the same functionality twice.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var contentFix = $('#contentfix');
    var leftMenu = $("#leftmenu");
    var menuToggle = $('#menutoggle');
    var htmlBody = $('html, body');
    var toggle = function(){
        htmlBody.animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
        if (leftMenu.is(":visible")) {
            contentFix.css('top','-10px');
        } else {
            contentFix.css('top','0px');
        }
    }
    menuToggle.on('click', function() {
        toggle();
    });
});
```